# I m having an ios app in "pending developer release" mode

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I m having an iOS app in "pending developer release" mode.which i released this Monday .The app is now showing

[image]

But still the app is not showing in the app store .when i tried to open the app from ituneconnect using "view app on store" link

[image].

it's showing the item not available [image: item not available]

How long it will take to be avaible on the app store .

also i havn't set any date from the price tab ;assuming as soon as i'll click the release app button ,the app will be get live in daily appstore refresh cycle(possible the next day ).but it's been three days.

ANY Idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for your app using the app store query string search like

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=yourBundleID

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems to vary.  My guess would be under 24hrs. Have you tried searching for the app via the App Store search, instead of using the web interface link?  Perhaps that link is invalid, and the app is actually live?

Answer (score 1):

That's completely normal. I remember I was scared when my first app was ready for sale but I couldn't find it in the App Store. It usually takes about a day to actually be in the App Store.